# Data Generating Process in R

Tags: r, volatility

Do you know how to conduct the data generating process using the GARCH model to get the volatility in R?

```
w=0.0000041584
a=0.15683
b=0.80359
d=7.3125
rt=1
sigma<-numeric(500)
sigma[1]=sqrt(w/(1-a-b))
for (i in 1:500) {
  z<-rt(100,5)/sqrt(d/(d-2))
  l=z*sigma[i]
  sigma[i+1]=sqrt(w+a*l*l+b*sigma[i]*sigma[i])
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `sigma` instead of `sigema`?

Comment: yes,I am sorry.